# Sorting by least significant digit

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, digit

I am trying to write a program that accepts an array of five four digit numbers and sorts the array based off the least significant digit. For example if the numbers were 1234, 5432, 4567, and 8978, the array would be sorted first by the last digit so the nest sort would be 5432, 1224, 4597, 8978. Then after it would be 1224, 5432, 8978, 4597. And so on until it is fully sorted.

I have wrote the code for displaying the array and part of it for sorting. I am not sure how to write the equations I need to compare each digit. This is my code for sorting by each digit so far:

```
public static void sortByDigit(int[] array, int size)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
      {


      }

      for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
      { 
        System.out.println(array[i]); 
      }
    }
  }
```

I am not sure what to put in the nested for loop. I think I need to use the modulus.

I just wrote this to separate the digits but I don't know how to swap the numbers or compare them.

```
int first = array[i]%10;
   int second = (array[i]%100)/10;
   int third = (array[i]%1000)/10;
   int fourth = (array[i]%10000)/10;
```

Would this would go in the for loop?

Comment: I guess you need to do a stable sort, by the way, otherwise this algorithm definitely won't work. That means, if the digits you are comparing are equal, do not move the numbers.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It's how do you read the last digit of the number?

Comment: You are right about needing modulus. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation 
Knowing that should greatly simplify this problem

Comment: Also, you say 5 four digit numbers, but your example is 4 four digit numbers. And your code assumes the number of numbers is the same as the number of digits.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? I was think I I could separate each digit but I don't think that will work because I have no way to compare.

Comment: It's easy to compare digits, they are just ints, so just compare them with < or > as normal.

Comment: If we know it's a multidigit number and we want the 1s digit, we can modulus it! number%10 = 1s digit. So 1234%10 = 4. If we want the 10s digit: (1234%100)/10     Alternatively, you can have a variable to shift left for digit, so number%(10^digit)/(10^(digit-1)) Ugh, is there a formula formatter?

Comment: What about digits that have the least sig the same? do you compare the 2nd sig?

Comment: They are predefined numbers so none of them are the same digits in significant places.

Comment: If `size` is the number of integers you're sorting, you may not need it; `array.length` gives you the length of the array.  You'd need a separate `size` only if you intend `array` to possibly have some unused elements.

Comment: Is what I just added useful at all?

Comment: You got the second digit right. Third digit should be: `int third = (array[i]%1000)/100;` and fourth digit can be `int fourth = array[i]/1000` What you should try after that is integrating a sort of some sort.

Comment: Unless this is homework, wouldn't it be simpler to just use `Integer.toString()` and compare the characters starting from the end? Might even be faster if you use the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem is mainly just getting the value of a digit at a certain index. Once you can do that, you should be able to formulate a solution.

Your hunch that you need modulus is absolutely correct. The modulo operator (`%`) returns the remainder on a given division operation. This means that saying `10 % 2` would equal 0, as there is no remainder. `10 % 3`, however, would yield 1, as the remainder is one.

Given that quick background on modulus, we just need to figure out how to make a method that can grab a digit. Let's start with a general signature:

```
public int getValueAtIdx(int value, int idx){
}
```

So, if we call `getValueAtIdx(145, 2)`, it should return `1` (assuming that the index starts at the least significant digit). If we call `getValueAtIdx(562354, 3)`, it should return `2`. You get the idea.

Alright, so let's start by using figuring out how to do this on a simple case. Let's say we call `getValueAtIdx(27, 0)`. Using modulus, we should be able to grab that `7`. Our equation is `27 % x = 7`, and we just need to determine `x`. So `27` divided by what will give us a remainder of `7`? `10`, of course! That makes our equation `27 % 10 = 7`.

Now that's all find and dandy, but how does `10` relate to `0`? Well, let's try and grab the value at index `1` this time (`2`), and see if we can't figure it out. With what we did last time, we should have something like `27 % x = 27` (WARNING: There is a rabbit-hole here where you could think `x` should be `5`, but upon further examination it can be found that only works in this case). What if we take the `10` we used earlier, but square it (`index+1`)? That would give us `27 % 100 = 27`. Then all we have to do is divide by `10` and we're good.

So what would that look like in the function we are making?

```
public int getValueAtIdx(int value, int idx){
    int modDivisor = (int) Math.pow(10, (idx+1));
    int remainder  = value % modDivisor;
    int digit      = remainder / (modDivisor / 10);
    return digit;
}
```

Ok, so let's to back to the more complicated example: `getValueAtIdx(562354, 3)`.

In the first step, `modDivisor` becomes `10^4`, which equals `10000`.

In the second step, `remainder` is set to `562354 % 10000`, which equals `2354`.

In the third and final step, `digit` is set to `remainder / (10000 / 10)`. Breaking that down, we get `remainder / 1000`, which (using integer division) is equal to `2`.

Our final step is return the digit we have acquired.

EDIT: As for the sort logic itself, you may want to look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts) for a good idea.

The general process is to compare the two digits, and if they are equal move on to their next digit. If they are not equal, put them in the bucket and move on.